# Sizing a rectangle in a borderpane

Tags: javafx-8, borderpane

I want to have a rectangle at the center of a borderpane but i want to make sure that the rectangle's size will follow the size of the center of the borderpane, how can we do that?

PS: I'm using JavaFX 8 (no FXML file just java code).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through this Document. it will help you better understand the Javafx Borderpane
[Link](http://dammsebastian.blogspot.com/2012/03/javafx-20-layot-panes-borderpane.html)

Comment: It's weird because it isn't working for me :/
is it because i'm using a personalized class that extends Parent ?

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.